# What is the exact usage of shift operator in C

Tags: c, bit-shift

I thought shift operator shifts the memory of the integer or the char on which it is applied but the output of the following code came a surprise to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint64_t number = 33550336;

    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&number;
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i < sizeof number; ++i)
        printf("%02x ", p[i]);
    printf("\n");

    //shift operation
    number = number<<4;

    p = (unsigned char *)&number;
    for (i=0; i < sizeof number; ++i)
        printf("%02x ", p[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The system on which it ran is little endian and produced the following output:

```
00 f0 ff 01 00 00 00 00 
00 00 ff 1f 00 00 00 00
```

Can somebody provide some reference to the detailed working of the shift operators?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

Comment: I think you are displaying your bytes in the wrong order. If the order of the bytes is reversed, then it would seem to make sense. Is your code targeting a 32 or 64 bit system?

Comment: @user957902 It makes sense on a little endian machine, like he says.

Comment: @Christain Rau I though that << shifted toward MSB. As displayed, it shifted towards LSB, assuming that MSB is towards left and LSB towards right which I think is the usual convention. I guess it all depends on wether you are looking at the actual memory storage or the resulting number you are trying to represent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question. The machine is *little endian*, which means the bytes are stored in memory with the least significant byte to the left. So your memory represents:

```
00 f0 ff 01 00 00 00 00 => 0x0000000001fff000
00 00 ff 1f 00 00 00 00 => 0x000000001fff0000
```

As you can see, the second is the same as the first value, shifted left by 4 bits.

Comment: Is it the "%02x" which outputs a single byte in the big endian format or it is stored in the memory that way?

Comment: @Amit `printf` prints numbers, the endianness doesn't matter. It only matters when you cast the `uint64_t*` to the `unsigned char*` and access the bytes individually.  Little endian means the order of the **bytes** is from the least significant to the most significant (see also "bit endianness"). printf still shows the value of those bytes correctly, no matter of how they're stored (and you can't know how they're stored because the smallest unit you can only address are bytes).

Comment: @AmitS A single byte doesn't have an endianness. The actual integer (right side in answer) is stored in memory with the least significant byte first. So when you reinterpret this memory as an array of chars, these chars don't get swapped around, as they are just chars and endianness doesn't apply to single bytes, only to multi-byte types (ints, floats, ...). So the char array shows you how it is laid out in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is right:

(1 * (256^3)) + (0xff * (256^2)) + (0xf0 * 256) = 33 550 336

(0x1f * (256^3)) + (0xff * (256^2)) = 536 805 376

33 550 336 * (2^4) = 536 805 376

Shifting left by 4 bits is the same as multiplying by 2^4.

Answer (score 2):

I think you printf confuses you. Here are the values:

```
     33550336 = 0x01FFF000
33550336 << 4 = 0x1FFF0000
```

Can you read you output now?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't shift the memory, but the bits. So you have the number:

```
00 00 00 00 01 FF F0 00
```

After shifting this number 4 bits (one hexadecimal digit) to the left you have:

```
00 00 00 00 1F FF 00 00
```

Which is exactly the output you get, when transformed to little endian.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is printing bytes in the order they are stored in memory, and the output would be different on a big-endian machine. If you want to print the value in hex just use %016llx. Then you'll see what you expect:

```
0000000001fff000
000000001fff0000
```

The second value is left-shifted by 4.